# Embed Mp4 Video File On My Website

Tags: video, embed

I have uploaded .mp4 video file in cpanel file manager.
Now i want to embed this .mp4 video file on my other website (with help of embed, object and iframes).
Please help how to code this.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Use your favorite search engine to research how to do this - There are plenty of resources

Comment: Since it's .mp4 why not use the video tag instead? Check google.com for **video tag tutorial** and **html5 iframe tutorial**. On this site we help each other to fix code issues when stuck, so you must have started something to get help here...

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [the `video` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).